# Azure Function fail to save master key in Key Vault

Tags: azure-functions

I'm trying to save Azure Function's master key in a key vault (Azure Function is deployed to Cosmic Windows containers).

I have configured 'AzureWebJobsSecretStorageType' to be 'keyvault' and set 'AzureWebJobsSecretStorageKeyVaultUri' to include the full kv URL; I have a managed identity and have added an access policy to give it secret Get, Set, List, and Delete permissions.
My Azure Function is successfully running, however, I'm not seeing a 'host--masterKey--master' secret in my kv. I was wondering how to fix this problem.
Thanks!

Comment: Are you using the function code to save the master key in key vault or any other way?

Comment: @HariKrishna I'm referring to this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings#azurewebjobssecretstoragekeyvaulturi and added the app settings as environment variables

Answer (score 1):

I'm able to get the Function Keys (Host Key, Master Key) in the Azure Key Vault by following the below steps given in this GitHub [8113 Issue Repo](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/8113#issuecomment-1049368882) of Azure Functions Host given by @[*liliankasem*](https://github.com/liliankasem)

1. Created the .NET 6 Azure Function App in the Azure Portal with the System Assigned Managed Identity Enabled. (Copy the object Id from the Identity Section)
   [image]
2. Create the Key Vault and Select the Secrets Management template in the Access Policies section of the Key Vault to create the access policy and then Copy the Key Vault Full URI.

[image]

3. In the Azure Portal Function App > Configuration >

[image]

4. Create a Http Trigger Function and Run once, then check the Azure Key Vault > Secrets section > you'll get all the Function Keys to be saved:

**Result**:

[image]